# Не работает @media запрос

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, media-queries

Есть код, хочу добавить медиа-запрос с разрешением 992px.
Смотрю через инспектор кода, но все как было, так и есть - стили медиа не применились. Помогите, в чем дело?

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700|Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="logo">
        <a href=""><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="header_logo"></a>
    </div>
    <style>
    .logo {
    padding-top: 52px;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .logo {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    }
    </style>
<!--мой код-->
</body>
```

Comment: Поставь @media в начале файла CSS.

Comment: Стили должны быть выше элементов, вроде бы аксиома, в противном случае возможны коллизии, зачем вам этот эксперимент??? если не поможет, то останется две причины - 1. Перекрытие другими стилями. 2. Ширина экрана больше ваших 992px.

Answer (score 0):

Все работает

```css
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  color: #fff;
}

.logo:after {
  content: 'Больше 992px';
  display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .logo {
    background: #00f;
  }
  .logo:after {
    content: 'Меньше 992px';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

А сам @media под нужным тегом виден в console? Если виден, но не применяется то, попробуй !important проставить, а лучше конечно без него обойтись каким-то другим образом. Мне самому будет интересно узнать - каким. А лучше всего выложите скрин из console - возможно стили перекрываются.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .logo {
    display: block !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало! =)